# Can't figure out why Datatable data get modified in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables, constants

I have some issues to figure out why my data gets modified i've tried to set my variable as a constant with `const` but it changes nothing.

In the code below I've tried to put it in an object and freeze it but it's doesn't work either.

here's my code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
CONST = { //try to create an object to freeze the data
  DATATABLE:$('#datatableFrais').DataTable().rows().data()
};
Object.freeze(CONST);
console.log(CONST);
});
function recupereData(){

   var csvData=[]; //the full data in arrays
   var entete=[]; //first line of my csv file 
   var txtData=""; //the string that will contain my file 
    var sepCol = arguments.sepCol|| ';'; //Column delimiter
    var sepLig = arguments.sepLig || '\n'; //Rows delimiter
   $('#datatabletFrais thead th').each(function(index, el) {
        // i get the header from my datatable
     var elem=$(el);

     entete.push(elem.text());
   })
   entete=entete.slice(0,-2);   
   csvData.push(entete);

   $.each(CONST.DATATABLE, function(index, val) {
        // The problem is here
        csvData.push(val);
        csvData[index+1].splice(-2,2); // cut the 2 last columns

   });
   $.each(csvData,function(index, val) {
        $.each(val, function(cle, valeur) {
            txtData+=valeur;
            txtData+=sepCol;
        });
        txtData+=sepLig;
   });
console.log(csvData);
console.log(txtData);
return txtData;
}
```

The first time i run the function it works fine but when i try to run it once again it uses the modified variable and i have 4 columns deleted in my csv file.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tested if `object.freeze()` is realiable, and works as you _expect_? I have never used it - `DATATABLE: $.extend({}, table.rows().data())` would work.

Comment: So i've tried this :
 `CONST = {
  DATATABLE2:.extend({}, $('#datatableFrais').DataTable().rows().data())
};` But it doesn't work and this object freeze works in this exemple : https://gist.github.com/blainsmith/6345780 but doesn't work for me ...